# can send message from my number to another number using python

Tags: python, set, twilio, sms

I want to send an sms using twilio or any other sms api with python but I want my personal number to show when i send a message

i tried using twilio but it didnt work while sending through twilio it shows a sender id not the sender number.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you send a message in Python:

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
                              body='Hi there',
                              from_='+15017122661',
                              to='+15558675310'
                          )
```

The reason it's showing the "Sender ID" (which I'm assuming you mean the message SID) is because you may be printing the message SID:

```
print(message.sid)
```

Instead of printing the `message.sid`, you can print the message's from number (sender's number):

```
print(message.from)
```

If you want to show your personal number (assuming you're sending the message to your number):

```
print(message.to)
```